# Self hosted Android syncing service

Tags: gratis, android, open-source, self-hosted, synchronization

For now, I'm fine with allowing Google/any other big company to manage my email; however I'd prefer to keep my storage documents/photos/contacts out of the storage of third party companies.

I'm looking for solutions that I can deploy on my own servers, preferably open source, and should auto sync a majority of these categories: (photos, documents, contacts, general storage).

I'd really love if the client supports certificates as well.

Could you also suggest corresponding opensource Photos Gallery apps?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/). I'm currently using its predecessor Owncloud for quite some time for syncing my Android with my PC. Nextcloud was forked from Owncloud about half a year ago and it seems like it will be more intensively developed in the future.

It is Open Source and clients and third-party apps exist for most platforms. With the webapp you can edit documents and have a photo gallery included. You can also share files or folders with a link.

It can sync ...

- Contacts
- Calendars
- Tasks
- Notes
- Newsfeed (optional plugin)
- Files/Photos

On the Android Site you can use [DAVdroid](https://davdroid.bitfire.at/) to sync contacts and calendars (available for a small donation on the Play Store and for free from FDroid Store) and [Notes](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=Nextcloud&fdid=it.niedermann.owncloud.notes) for syncing ... right, Notes.

For File Sync you can use the official Nextcloud app or use any webdav compatible Application.
(e.g. [Keepass2Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android) can directly access a keepass2 (kdbx) file via webdav)

A [search for Nextcloud on FDroid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=Nextcloud) gives some more possible apps.

Comment: Nextcloud doesn't has 2 way sync yet!